# Writing a node application and encountering an error when running 'node server.js'

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a node application and I recently switched from port 3000 to port 80 on my Mac Os X Lion machine (running 10.7.4) and whenever I run node server.js I get the following error

```
events.js:66
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:768:11)
    at HTTPServer.Server._listen2 (net.js:891:19)
    at listen (net.js:935:10)
    at HTTPServer.Server.listen (net.js:984:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ajain/Documents/Projects/Time-Feed/server.js:127:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Any idea on what I have to do to fix the issue?

Comment: Do you have any other server running on port 80?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to have the root privilege in order to listen on a port number below 1024. Therefore, you may use the `sudo` command.

```
sudo node server.js
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain why I had that issue?

Comment: @mosquito242 Its because ports < 1024 are privileged

Comment: @jcolebrand "and I recently switched from port 3000 to port 80" in the question.

Comment: I SWEAR that wasn't there before >.>

Comment: problem with using sudo to use ports below 1024 is the process remains open even when you close the terminal window. It's a pain to close the process.

Answer (score 2):

If sudo didn't help just change the port to something like 1234 or maybe 2000 or 3000.